# Excel VBA - How to get the next character of InStr?

Tags: string, excel, vba

```
s = "qweqweqwe12345"
mm = "qweqweqwe"

If InStr(mm,rr) <> 0 Then

 ' get the the next character or "12345"

End if
```

I need to get the next character after finding the mm string in rr.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    s = "qweqweqwe12345"
    mm = "qweqweqwe"

    If InStr(1, s, mm) <> 0 Then
        '~~> Find position of string1
        pos1 = InStr(1, s, mm)
        '~~> Find position of string2
        pos2 = InStr(pos1 + Len(mm), s, "12345")
        Debug.Print pos2
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something like:

```
Dim lFound As Long
s = "qweqweqwe12345"
mm = "qweqweqwe"

lFound = InStr(s, mm)
If lFound <> 0 Then MsgBox Mid$(s, lFound + Len(mm))
```

Comment: @SiddharthRout I don't know what you mean... ;)